# How can I make touchpad not change workspace in xubuntu 13.10?

Tags: xubuntu, touchpad, workspaces

In Xubuntu 13.10 horizontal scrolling changes workspace. I don't want it to, so how do I disable it?

In Lubuntu I can change ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting Manager -> Window Manager Tweaks -> Workspaces
and unchecking "User the mouse wheel on the desktop to switch workspaces"